# Flink cannot consume data from Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I encountered a problem when using flink to consume Kafka data. The flink program could not receive the data from Kafka, neither reported an error nor printed out. But when I use the Kafka consumer program to consume Kafka data, I can consume normally. I don’t think it’s a problem with the Kafka cluster. I’ve been thinking for a long time but I haven’t found the answer. Please provide ideas or solutions. My Kafka cluster is on a virtual machine. and the virtual machine can communicate with each other. Below is my flink program:

```
import org.apache.flink.api.common.eventtime.WatermarkStrategy;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.SimpleStringEncoder;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.SimpleStringSchema;
import org.apache.flink.configuration.MemorySize;
import org.apache.flink.connector.file.sink.FileSink;
import org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.KafkaSource;
import org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.enumerator.initializer.OffsetsInitializer;
import org.apache.flink.core.fs.Path;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.CheckpointingMode;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStreamSource;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.OutputFileConfig;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.rollingpolicies.DefaultRollingPolicy;


public class Cityweather {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        
        env.enableCheckpointing(1000, CheckpointingMode.AT_LEAST_ONCE);
        env.getCheckpointConfig().setMinPauseBetweenCheckpoints(3000);

        KafkaSource<String> kafkaSource = KafkaSource.<String>builder()
                .setBootstrapServers("hadoop100:9092")
                .setTopics("POC_test")
                .setGroupId("my-groupsdads")
                .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.earliest())
                .setValueOnlyDeserializer(new SimpleStringSchema())
                .build();

        DataStreamSource<String> weathertest = env.fromSource(kafkaSource, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "weather_test");

        FileSink build = FileSink.forRowFormat(new Path("D:\\IDEA2021_Projects\\Flink\\data"), new SimpleStringEncoder<>("UTF-8"))
                .withBucketAssigner(new MyBucketAssigner())
                .withRollingPolicy(DefaultRollingPolicy.builder().withMaxPartSize(MemorySize.ofMebiBytes(1))
                        .build())
                .withBucketCheckInterval(10000)
                .withOutputFileConfig(OutputFileConfig.builder().withPartSuffix(".txt").withPartPrefix("Test——").build())
                .build();

        weathertest.print();
        weathertest.sinkTo(build);

        env.execute("CityWeather");

    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMXlS.png)

I have tried the configuration properties of KafkaSource, but nothing has changed, and I have also tried canceling checkpoints, but more errors will appear

Comment: Is there anything written in the JobManager and/or TaskManager logs?